# How to convert JSON to XML?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Is it possible to store data in firebase, then get that data and use it to create an xml file? Not specifically create, but use the data so that it gets the data the browser will view it as an xml file.

Comment: Firebase is a JSON datastore. So is your question whether JSON can be converted to XML? If so, I can't imagine that hasn't been covered before. If that is not what you're asking, please edit your question to clarify and show what you've already done. As it stands your question is incredibly broad.

Comment: Yes, exactly. JSON data saved in firebase will be used and convert into an xml file which then the browser will show. If this is possible, does anyone know how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+convert+json+to+xml

Comment: Have you try this https://devtoolsonline20190908040816.azurewebsites.net/DevTools/Convert_JSON2XML?